# Excel function coded in c++ with the excel sdk : I want it NOT to trigger calculation when used in excel's function wizard

Tags: c++, multithreading, excel, xll

**I am using [excel c/c++ sdk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687883(v=office.12).aspx) >= 2007 (I put the link for 2007 for reference) and excel >= 2007. *I coded (with the sdk) an xll* that is providing to excel a function F**, and this function F can be called in two ways in an excel sheet : 1) write directly the formula involving F in an excel cell/range of cell or in the formula bar 2) **write `=F` in an excel cell, and click on the fx icon on the left of formula bar and use excel's function wizard**.

Only the 2nd case interests me. In this case, this opens the dialog box of excel's function wizard : a windows with n cells, each corresponding to one argument of F (assuming that  F is a function taking n argumebts). **Now, by default, has you enter something in one of the cells, excel trigger recalculation of the function.**

This is particularly handy when you don't know the function and want to "discover it", because you can see if what you type represents a correct argument for F etc, for instance errors do appears etc.

But **if F relies on a very intensive numerical routine (in c++), then all the recalculations take a way too long time, and are freezing the wizard. (Because each time a cell in dialog box is modified, a recalculation is triggerde.)**

Therefore I would like to do the following : **deactivate somehow the recalculation when the function is "called" through the function wizard. This is let's say the low quality solution.**

**Ideally, I would like to do the following : autorize the recalculations to be triggered, but ensure (in the c++ excel sdk code) that they are done in a different "thread" that the one in which the wizard is called. So that there wouldn't be freezing anymore.** (So that the handy part of the wizard could be preserved.) Apparently, if I understand [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff796219(v=office.14).aspx) correctly (maybe not, in case it is not the same problem) it is not possible under excel 2007 but it is in excel >= 2010.

As the users of F are using various version of excel -- mainly 2007 but even 2003 for some of them -- even if I am tempted to push a move to 2010 (come on, we are after all already to 2013 in real life !), I won't do it, for the mentionned reason, but also because it is not satisfying for me to have something working only for some excel versions...

So I would like to find another solution. I heard people talking about RTD for this, but i am not sure.

That's why any insights are welcome ! Thx a lot in advance. (And sorry for the lenght of the question.)

Comment: Wanted to create the tag excel-sdk, but it does not existe, and I am not reputed enough (<1500) to do it. Anyone able to do it and put the right tag is welcome. (The tag `xll` must be kept.)

Comment: You can check if one of the standard command bar controls is enabled.  They are not enabled when the formula wizard is displayed.

Comment: Hum, where could I "check" this ? In the c++ code for sure, but then how ? Because I'm not in VBA, and I'm not sure that I could access CommandBarControl from the c++ excel sdk...

Comment: My bad, just realized I haven't precised (even if I put the tag) that I coded an xll providing the function F to excel. I have just edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687909.aspx#Y241) which discusses the method to be used, with C++ examples 
This is the method used by the frameworks such as XLDNA and XLL Plus (and I think also by Addin Express).

I don't think that using the asynchronous UDF signature would help because the function wizard uses the Evaluate method under the covers rather than an actual re-calculation (but I have not actulally tried it)

Answer (score 0):

A work around would be to check if the parameters are **missing** or **nil** at the beginning of your routing and only calculate if all parameters are set. I know it won't prevent recalculation every time the user opens the dialog and changes some values, but at least it would prevent recalculation until the user sets all parameters.

You may add a additional parameter (e.g. trigger) and check if the parameter is set to a certain value (e.g. 1) before calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good idea. Already thought of something like this : would it be at home, I could do it temporarily, but at work such a solution would't be accepted, for obvious reasons. Sorry !